# Checking .wav files for similarity

Tags: java, audio, audio-fingerprinting

I'm trying to compare .wav files for similarity.
I used the google musicg library for that but I get bad scores for similar sounds. I compare two car motor sound from the same car and the recordings sounds are very similar to a human voice but I get fingerprintSimilarity scores like 0.012468828. The recordings are made with a microphone.

What is the reason for getting these bad scores?

I use:

```
Wave wave = new Wave("wav1.wav");
Wave wave1 = new Wave("wav4.wav");
FingerprintSimilarity fingerprintSimilarity = wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave1);
float score = fingerprintSimilarity.getScore();
float similarity = fingerprintSimilarity.getSimilarity();
System.out.println("Similar sound :"+ "Score : " + score + "\n  Similarity : "+ similarity);
```

My goal is to create a program that can find a car model from its motor sound.

Are there other libraries which are working better or is it a problem of audio-fingerprints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be based on fingerprints.

What you should do however is:

1. Get data
2. Get data annotation (what sound belongs to what motor)
3. Extract audio features from data
4. Process data for eliminate redudancy
5. Develop a classification model
6. Evaluate the model
7. Judge what features are best for you problem
8. Implement the model in an application

As you can see it is not just as simple as it is for music. The reason is that for music some people have already done the above (many, many times) and have developed models for similarity. For your domain and application specific model I haven't heard of anything. Thus, either you should check in sound events similatiry papers or check that someone maybe have developed an app for sound events (cause what you have is a sound event).

P.S. For the above steps you can use MARSYS, JAudio, Sonic Visualizer and MIRToolbox along with WEKA.

Answer (score 1):

As the names suggest, the library you are using is developed for analysis of music. The similarity measure is trying to find "fingerprints", i.e. distinctive pieces of sound, whereas the sound of motor is very monotonic, I would guess the algorithm ends up finding really weird pieces and comparing them - this scenario is unlikely to get you good results.

If your goal is to analyze the sounds of different motors for similarities, you should try using plain spectral analysis. If you plan analyzing music, on the other hand, you better try your algorithm on pieces of real music.

Comment: My goal is to create an program which can find a car model from its motor sound. I thought this would be possible with fingerprints. I tried it first with music which works great but I don't need to analyze music. Just motor sounds.

Comment: Then I would suggest you look at the average waveform of one motor beat - this can be described in terms of shape or (better) spectral properties, but certainly not musical fingerprints.

Comment: How do I get or create the average waveform? I didn't really understand what you are meaning.

Comment: The first approximation of engine noise is pure low sound, i.e. a sine wave. Then, instead of a smooth wave it becomes a weird shape that still repeats itself over and over. That would be the second, still very simple, approximation of the sound. That what I meant. This is still very simplistic, though.

Comment: I reckon this model would be able to tell a 4cyl from 8cyl already. But with changing engine revs I imagine the shape will start changing - then, do you want to be able to do the job at any rev speed or only idle ones?

Comment: The best model would try to calculate how the source sounds (the explosion sound in the cylinders, the clicking of the valves and maybe few more sources) is transformed spectrally when it goes trough the whole system, then the model will remain valid at various rev speeds.

Comment: So, to start the experiments going I would first learn how to process the sound to find the pattern that repeats itself at about 17 times a second, and then create a collection of such patterns and analyze them using some good visual sound processing tool. The general rule is: if you can't do something manually (say, classify a sound somebody gives you), it is unlikely that you would be able to create a program that would do that for you in some magical automatic way.

Comment: Of course this is not the only possible approach. Another route would be to 1) calculate power spectrum or a similar characteristic of the sound and 2) train a classifier over the result. Algorithms for both steps would be readily available.